# How to increase the lifetime of the session?

Tags: asp.net, webserver

My current properties:
`Session.Timeout = 500;` -  ignored;
On the server properties - `Session State Time-out` = 500 - didn't help.

Comment: WHY do you want to increase this timeout? That will mean that session-objects will occupy memory on the server for a longer time. Maybe a better solution would be to have some "keep alive" mechanism to prevent session timeouts.

Comment: What "keep alive" mechanism you can advice for me

Comment: @TleckAipov: Here's one: ["session defibrillator"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10550/The-Defibrillator-Keeping-ASP-NET-Session-Alive-Ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the session timeout in the [`web.config`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa306178.aspx) file?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="500"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You might also want to have a look this site for other reasons: http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/session-expires-before-timeout-value-specified-in-web-config

As @Hans has suggested, you can also use a "keep alive" mechanism instead of the sledgehammer method of increasing the session. 
Here's one: ["session defibrillator"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10550/The-Defibrillator-Keeping-ASP-NET-Session-Alive-Ad)

Comment: Yes. I did it in web.config. And then it appeared in server properties.

Comment: How are you determing that the session does not work as expected and what does that mean? The timeout starts on idle time, so when the user is inactive. Also, are you lumping together forms-authentication with session?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the Timeout of the sessionState element in your web.config:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
    timeout="number of minutes"
    cookieName="session identifier cookie name"
    cookieless=
         "[true|false|AutoDetect|UseCookies|UseUri|UseDeviceProfile]"
    regenerateExpiredSessionId="[True|False]"
    sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
    sqlCommandTimeout="number of seconds"
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="[True|False]"
    useHostingIdentity="[True|False]"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
    stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"
    customProvider="custom provider name">
    <providers>...</providers>
</sessionState>
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx)